# Javascript/Typescript: Best way to append value in object based on condition from other object

Tags: javascript, typescript

**Updated object keys**

```
    let conditionedObject = {
        "isNameRequired": true,
        "isCityRequired": false,
        "isPostRequired": true
    };
    
    let myTotalData = {
     data: {
        "givenName": 'myname',
        "street":"mystreet",
        "cityName": 'mycity',
        "postcode": 'mypost'
      }
    };

let resultData = {};
```

Both condionedObject and myTotalData comes from different source.
I would like to know the best way to create a new object based on the condionedObject,
example my condionedObject says I need only **name** and **post** so my `resultData` should return `{"givenName":"myname","postcode":"mypost"}`

*conditionedObject.isNameRequired* is for *myTotalData.data.givenName*, *conditionedObject.isPostRequired* is for *myTotalData.data.postcode*,
*conditionedObject.isCityRequired* is for *myTotalData.data.cityName*, all this will say whether myTotalData key is required to be placed in the new object.

Thanks in advance for all the suggestions and helps

Comment: All, The data of objects conditionedObject and myTotalData comes from different sources I gave sample key names, consider removing "is" from key names are not an option. consider them as isNameRequired, isCityRequired, isPostRequired..etc

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

You need to change the keys in the object `conditionedObject` and remove the `is-` prefix so that they are the same as the keys in `myTotalData`. This way the check is easier later.

Then it's pretty straight-forward.

```js
let conditionedObject: {[key: string]: boolean} = {
    "isName": true,
    "isCity": false,
    "isPost": true
};

type DataType = {[key: string]: string};
let myTotalData: DataType = {
    "name": 'myname',
    "city": 'mycity',
    "post": 'mypost'
};

let resultData: DataType = {};
for(const key in conditionedObject) {
    // Ensure that the key is really part of this object
    if(!conditionedObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }
    
    if(!conditionedObject[key]) {
        continue;
    }
    
    const dataKey = key.startsWith("is")
        ? key.charAt(2).toLowerCase() + key.substring(3)
        : key;

    if(myTotalData.hasOwnProperty(dataKey)) {
        resultData[dataKey] = myTotalData[dataKey];
    }
}

console.log(resultData);
```

Output:

```
{
    name: "myname",
    post: "mypost"
}
```

Comment: I cannot have the same keys in both the objects as they both come from different source, is there any other efficient way with the sample objects that I have provided.

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer to use the original `conditionedObject`.

Comment: not working in TS and got the below error for line 
**if(!conditionedObject[key]) {**

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ isName: boolean; isCity: boolean; isPost: boolean; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ isName: boolean; isCity: boolean; isPost: boolean; }'*

Comment: @sunilsmith That error can be resolved by specifying the types of the data objects, as `{[key: string]: boolean}` and `{[key: string]: strnig}`. Updated the answer with the changes, and it no longer has that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

In this case I recommend you to create a new object to store the relationship between properties:

```js
  

  let conditionedObject = {
  "isNameRequired": true,
  "isCityRequired": false,
  "isPostRequired": true
};

let myTotalData = {
  data: {
    "givenName": 'myname',
    "street":"mystreet",
    "cityName": 'mycity',
    "postcode": 'mypost'
  }
};

const reference = {
  "isNameRequired": "givenName",
  "isCityRequired": "cityName",
  "isPostRequired": "postcode"
}

let resultData = {};

resultData =Object.entries(conditionedObject).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
   if(value && myTotalData.data[reference[key]]) {
     const prop = reference[key]; 
     obj[prop] = myTotalData.data[prop];
   }
   return obj;
}, {});

console.log(resultData);
```

Comment: your entries.reduce way of identifying the object is really good but the problem is that I don't have similar object structure or key name. I have updated my question can you try providing a efficient solution *@lissettdm*

Comment: I think, you need a way to map the props, could be something like this  {"isNameRequired": "givenName"}, otherwise it is difficult to identify which properties to map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that, if you can be sure that the `conditionedObject`  keys are always equal your `myTotalData` keys, but capitalized and with "is" on the front:

```js
let capitalize = str => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
let prependIs = str => "is" + str

let conditionedObject = {
  "isName": true,
  "isCity": false,
  "isPost": true
};

let myTotalData = {
  "name": 'myname',
  "city": 'mycity',
  "post": 'mypost'
};

let filterData = (data, conditionObj) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data)
  .filter(([key, _]) => conditionObj[prependIs(capitalize(key))]))

// More verbose alternative for browsers which doesn't support `Object.fromEntries()`
let filterDataAlt = (data, conditionObj) => {
  let result = {}
  let filteredEntries = Object.entries(data)
    .filter(([key, _]) => conditionObj[prependIs(capitalize(key))])
  for (let [key, value] of filteredEntries) {
    result[key] = value
  }
  return result
}

console.log(filterData(myTotalData, conditionedObject))
console.log(filterDataAlt(myTotalData, conditionedObject))
```